# How to vertically align digits with Bootstrap on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, fonts

I use Bootstrap, but unfortunately numbers, especially 5 and 7, are not vertically aligned with other digits in Firefox. Please see my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sf7SRUgGUMqfJLSzkHs5?p=preview).

With the following html code:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h4>12345678910</h4>
```

the output looks in Chromium like this:

[image: text in chromium]

Firefox renders this:

[image: text in firefox]

Note how the digits 5 and 7 are rendered with a different vertical offset.

Can you suggest a cross-compatible font for all standard browsers (ff, chrome, ie, safari)?